# How to pronounce "slash" in giving an address

Tags: symbols, reading

How to pronounce "slash" in giving an address, meaning the corner of 2 streets? 
I live at *1/9* Park Lane. Should it be read as *one slash nine* Park Lane?

Comment: That is how I'd expect it to be spoken or read.

Comment: I’m skeptical that it means the corner of two streets.

Comment: Addressing formats are highly dependent on locale, and how it is pronounced will likely depend on where the person pronouncing it calls home. Someone from Boston might interpret it as a fractional street number (i.e. one-ninth Park Lane). Someone from the borough of Queens in New York City might think it is a typo for a [hyphenated street number](https://stevemorse.org/census/changes/QueensFormat.htm). The slash is not used in U.S. or Canadian addressing so far as I can tell, so there is no convention otherwise on this side of the pond.

Answer (score 2):

This may well be one of those common things showing *significant regional variation*.

In my part of the world (Melbourne, Australia), this address wouldn't refer to "the corner of 2 streets" as suggested in the question. It would mean "internal address 1" (e.g. a unit, an apartment, or in general the *ordinal* dwelling/office of several such on that site) at "street address 9 Park Lane".

As such, it would more often be read aloud as *"one of nine Park Lane"* or, to disambiguate, *"**unit** one of nine Park Lane"* (even if it's an apartment rather than a "unit"), although pronouncing the "/" as "slash" is also common.

Given it's *spoken*, I'm finding it hard to locate any online evidence to support this, so you'll just have to take my word for it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, in the US / is called "slash".
But perhaps something else is common in the UK.
I find this:

> **stroke**
>   NOUN
>   2.2 A short printed or written diagonal line typically separating characters or figures

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stroke)

..

I think I saw this in the Terry Gilliam movie *Brazil*.  In the big office building, the number on a door has a / character, but they pronounce it "stroke".

Answer (score 1):

In the US, / is pronounced slash.  However, I would not have the foggiest idea what 1/9 Park Lane meant as an address.  I might take a guess that it meant 9 Park Lane but the 1 would be a mystery. Likely, when you said that, I would say

> Huh?

It certainly does not convey that you are at the corner of Park Lane and some other street, much less **which** of the four corners you are at.

The way we would say it here is:

> I live at 9 Park Lane.  That is at the corner of Park Lane and
>   Parkland Avenue.  The building is (some identifying characteristic of
>   the building) and I'm in Apartment 6C.

As for what you would write down, if asked for your address in writing:

> Apartment 6c
>
> 9 Park Lane
>
> Park City
>
> State, Zip Code

The mailman does not need to be told that you are on a corner, or if he does, you are in deep kimchi.

As for references, as @Chappo said, you'll just have to take my word for it.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. That's the usual way to identify the houses that are on the corner of 2 streets in Russia, Ukraine . So, as far as I can see there is no such thing in the English speaking countries.